# MongoDb C# Driver - Get item by indexed field very slow

Tags: c#, mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I ran into performance issues when fetching filtered data on a small local database. I reduced the code (as below) to reproduce the issue.  The output is about 2000ms.

**Some additional information:**

- The queried collection contains 135,000 entries with 7 simple types each
- When running a similar query in something like RoboMongo  - db.TickerData.find({_id : ObjectId('5731d39062deb83134772e77')}).explain() - the totalExecutionTime is <1ms
- I am using the latest MongoDb server and C# driver versions
- The database is running locally (quad core 16Mb Ram) on the same dev/debug environment
- I noticed no difference in performance between indexed and non indexed fields when testing on other fields than the ID (which is always indexed)
- My first though was that the .Single() linq operation retrieves all the documents before doing a single search but from Google'ing it seems that all linq operations is transposed to MongoDB server side queries

Code:

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        new BaseRepository<TickerData>().GetById("5731d39062deb83134772e77");
        sw.Stop();
        Debug.Write(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    }
}

public class BaseRepository<T> : MongoBase where T : BaseEntity
{
    MongoDatabase DataBase { get; set; }
    protected IQueryable<T> Collection { get; set; }
    MongoCollection<BsonDocument> mCollection { get; set; }

    public BaseRepository()
    {
        DataBase = Server.GetDatabase("TradingBot");
        mCollection = DataBase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(typeof(T).Name);
        Collection = mCollection.AsQueryable<T>();
    }

    public T GetById(string ID)
    {
        return Collection.Single(i => i.Id.ToString() == ID);
    }

}
```

Update:
Suggest as per @rnofenko (see comments) made a huge improvement but still seem way to slow?

Comment: Your type conversion in `GetById` looks backwards in a way that could prevent using the index. Can you try `Collection.Single(i => i.Id == new ObjectId(ID));` instead?

Comment: Yes you are right that my ToString implementation was incorrect.  However using SingleAsync as per @mofenko's solution it prevented me from using a ToString on Id in any case.  Thus the usage was already correct and its performing too slow at 500-600ms

Comment: OK. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help here as I'm not able to reproduce what you're seeing and your example code isn't complete.

Comment: Hmmm... I have created the MCVE and now its performing well (50ms on 5mil records).  So my issue might be solved but I will update if I can reproduce the issue again.

Comment: Yes problem solved thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tricky moment.
You call extension method **Single** from **System.Linq**. In fact you load whole collection from DB and select by ID inside your application.

Instead you need to use MongoDB extension method - **SingleAsync** from **MongoDB.Driver.Linq**.

```
public async Task<T> GetById(string id)
{
    return await Collection.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == new ObjectId(id));
}
```

Comment: While this is a move in the right direction I am still not getting what Im hoping for. Using as suggested it brings the query down to 500ms (still a far cry from the <1ms other clients like RoboMongo get by querying the DB).  A query on 356,000 on 3 fields (with compound index) takes 2500ms.  This is down from 17,000ms  a huge improvement but still feels way to slow?

Comment: @JohnnyHK is right about ID. Convert the argument instead of the field.

Comment: As per response to @JohnnyHK above this was already corrected as the new method forced me to.  So the issue persist.